# Wordpress orderby custom taxonomy category

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I've got some custom taxonomy terms that function as categories for a custom post type called 'beer'. All beer posts fall into 1 of 3 categories.

This is how I register the custom post type category:

```
  register_taxonomy(
            'beer_categories',
            'beer',
            array(
                'hierarchical' => true,
                'label'        => __( 'Beer categories' ),
                'rewrite'      => array( 'slug' => __( 'bieren/categorieen' ) ),
                'supports'     => array( 'thumbnail' )
            )
        );
```

When fetching the posts with custom post type 'beer', how would I order the results by this taxonomy category?

For example:

- Product 1 (category 1)
- Product 4 (category 1)
- Product 6 (category 1)
- Product 2 (category 2)
- Product 3 (category 3)
- Product 5 (category 4)

I have tried all sorts of arguments for the get_posts() function. 
But so far no luck, so please help.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'beer',
    'posts_per_page' => - 1,
    'orderby'        => 'beer_categories',
    'order'          => 'ASC'
);

$posts = get_posts( $args );
```

Comment: As far as I know `get_posts` can't order by taxonomy like that... you can do 3 separate queries for each category using `tax_query` argument, but not order as simply as you expect to. Either use 3 queries, or loop through the results and split them out in to the order you want them / 3 separate arrays

Comment: That would be quite disappointing. But that explains the forum posts i've seen about looping though terms and then querying results.